# Python: how to write this the "pythonic way"?

Tags: python

I know this is not "nice" python stuff:

```
username = u'{0}{1}{2}'.format(
    form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@', 1)[0],
    u'_at_',
    form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@', 1)[1]
)
```

How would you write this in a more pythonic = easy to understand & optimized way?

Comment: The format string is wrong. There should be a `{2}` if you expect those three values to be there.

Comment: Well, it’s very simple: If your code is *broken*, and you want to make that code prettier, then it’s absolutely not clear whether you want us to keep it broken while doing that. And I don’t know why you react with so much hostility. I was merely pointing out a mistake (I can’t know that you know that?!), and besides I even answered the question.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't it suck when you come asking for free help and people give you free help? Given that the middle part is a literal, `'{0}_at_{1}'.format(*form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@', 1))` would also work

Comment: Watch my history you'll see I give much more free help than I ask.

Comment: Then you should know pretty well, that we can’t just assume things. We point things out we notice, and I really don’t get what your problem is.

Comment: So you'd be happy if someone responded to a comment of yours the way you just responded to poke's?

Comment: I have no time for arguing about that, poke's answer is perfect and i take  jonrsharpe for my students to show how to write two differents things, so they understand what people sometimes call "python black magic".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your intention is just to replace the `@` symbol, just replace that:

```
username = form.cleaned_data['email'].replace('@', '_at_')
```

---

To expand a bit (because I feel like it), if you don’t have a simple replacement as above, you generally want to avoid calling `str.split` more than once on the same separator. So the obvious first step would be to store the result first:

```
data = form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@', 1)
username = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(data[0], '_at_', data[1])
```

Next, as others already pointed out, you should move constants into the format string:

```
username = '{0}_at_{2}'.format(data[0], data[1])
```

And then, since you’re only passing the (only two) elements of `data` to the function, you can use argument unpacking, at which point you can also inline the data again:

```
username = '{0}_at_{2}'.format(*form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@', 1))
```

An alternative solution, which works in situations when you split more than once, would be to join on your replacement string:

```
username = '_at_'.join(stringWithMultipleAts.split('@'))
```

Comment: Also note that the `split('@', 1)` version would fail if there wasn't actually an `@` present in the string, due to trying to read from the out of bounds index `data[1]`. That's another reason why the `join` version is superior, even if only a single `@` is expected to be present. (Alternatively you could explicitly check for the presence of the `@` symbol before the rest of the code.)

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
user, host = form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@')
username = u'{0}_at_{1}'.format(user, host)
```